# How to run select statements within true ,false conditions of select if()

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run query like below in MYSQL DB. Its not working. Can anyone provide correct syntax for this?

```
SET @var="sql";
select if(@var==sql,
select col1,col2,col3 from tableA,
select col5,col6,col6 from tableB);
```

Basically i want to execute different queries based on the value of @var.
if @var='sql'
then query1
else if @var='mysql'
then query2
else if @var='oracle'
then query3

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select col1,col2,col3 from tableA WHERE @var = 'sql'
UNION ALL
select col1,col2,col3 from tableB WHERE @var != 'sql'
```

If `condition` IS NULL then none rows will be returned - adjust the condition in 2nd subquery in this case.

Comment: I updated the question a bit more, can you please help.

Comment: @mohdaamerhussain Updated according to your edition.

Comment: its not working.. @var is not column of any table. so how this will work? Additionally where condition is already present for both tables like 'select col1,col2 from tableA where col6='XYZ';

Comment: i tried few times, doesn't work. Please assist further

Comment: @mohdaamerhussain Fiddle added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IF` statement instead of the `IF` method

E.g. :

```sql
IF @var="sql" THEN
   select col1,col2,col3 from tableA;
ELSE
   select col5,col6,col6 from tableB;
END IF;
```

Based on https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/ (im not affiliated with the source but it helped me)